# a website design : how do I combine node.js with php?

Tags: php, node.js, codeigniter, mongodb

I am planning to make a website which shows location information up.

The thing is, since the pages will be interactive to users and I am thinking of using node.js and mongoDB(pretty capable for node.js isn't it?).

Please recommend me which languages are fitting on node.js & mongoDB.

Python? or should I use jade for the development?

and plus, will be PHP Codeigniter helpful?

(I am used to developing with PHP and I am wondering if PHP & node.js combination is nice)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: tell me the current trend of developing with node.js please.

Comment: The problem is, the entire answer depends on your requirements and with your post showing almost none of them, we're unable to provide you with comments specific to your usecase...

Comment: Oops, I didn't write in detail.

Comment: To be short, first of all I wanna know which language is the best for node.js and mongoDB (to make a web site like yelp with social features). which language is the most poplular now?

Comment: First of all, that depends on your hoster. If you have a PHP-only hosting contract (PHP+MySQL = most cheap contracts) you can't use NodeJS. In any other case, using them together, could get somewhat hairy because you have to configure a reverse proxy for nodejs.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The server I am going to use is EC2 the amazon one, so I am not worried about the server's capability. Then which language would be nice for nodeJS? according to your saying, I gotta abandon PHP with nodeJS planning. can I use nodeJS with mongoDB only(independently)?(without php, jsp..sorta)

Comment: It's not neccessary to abandon it, it's just uncommon two use two totally different technologies in that way. That doesn't mean it's wrong, however. I assume, by language you mean template language? I, personally, like Jade, but other people might like EJS or ECO. You can take a look at frequently used packages on NPM here: https://npmjs.org/browse/depended . As you can see, jade, is one of the most-used templating systems for NodeJS. However, I have bad experiences with PHP implementations of Jade.

Comment: yeah, Jade was pretty nice to use when I took a look before. I think i am not getting the concept of nodeJS. I was thinking of server-client communicating using nodeJS, HTML coding with a framework(just like as you said, e.g. jade) and PHPs for the rest of things.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you need PHP for the rest? Generally, I'd use ExpressJS in NodeJS to handle the entire application, without resorting to other languages. I'll write an answer to avoid prolonged discussions in comments.

Comment: Uh I was totally misunderstanding for nodeJS. What I thought of nodeJS was it works only for server-client async/sync communication. just like a communicator and that's why I said php for the rest. Could you recommend nodeJS lecture pages on the web? I think I should study pretty hard before I'm jumping into it.

Comment: i've heard that facebook is using node.js and PHP both(they compile php into c though). Why are they using them together? are they using php for maintaining the entire service and nodeJS for asynchronous communications?

Comment: I don't know the specifics about the Facebook case, but NodeJS is new and admins usually prefer not to change existing systems. As far as I know most large webservices use NodeJS to be able to handle a large number of connections, especially for JSON-like return values.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if you're understanding *asynchronous* correctly in this context. PHP can handle multiple requests as well (because the webserver runs multiple php instances concurrently). However, that approach usually doesn't scale and in my experience PHP scripts tend to have quite a high overhead especially for DB IO in high-load situations, even if numerous accleration technologies have been developed.

Comment: Oh I get the conception now. You helped me a lot. I should get some books for nodeJS right away. Could you let me know your email if you are okay? I need some advices when I face some problems in developing. Thank you very much anyways!

Comment: Sure, just use the email on my SO page: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2597135/uli-kohler . Please feel free to remind me to answer you if I don't respond, I get an incredible amount of emails. EDIT: ah, sorry, not publicly visible, just use ukoehler <at> techoverflow.net

Comment: Okay. Thank you very much. I was kind of a blind man lol I will email you later. Munich was the greatest city ever, by the way!(I've been there 2yrs ago. can't forget Hofbräuhaus haha) HAVE A NICE DAY!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally I'd prefer not to use two different languages for comparatively simple applications (if your usecase is simple). There might be usecases where you can't avoid this, for example you have to use libraries that only exist in either one of the languages.

I'd use Jade with ExpressJS as Backend, however I consider the template language to be a highly personal Choice. See http://expressjs.com/api.html for an ExpressJS example

See https://npmjs.org/browse/depended for a list of popular NodeJS packages. Some people prefer to use EJS (embedded javascript) or ECO (embedded coffeescript) or one of numerous other templating systems instead of Jade.

Please also consider to use [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org) instead of writing the JS yourself (CoffeeScript is automatically converted into JS. It adds some neat features that are easy to get wrong when you're writing plain JS.

From a performance standpoint, NodeJS is best when you have many API calls that return a small amount of data. I've made good experiences with ExpressJS performance using Jade as backend.

I can recommend the [NodeJS beginner book](http://www.nodebeginner.org/), however, this is, as always, highly subjective.

It's difficult for me to Judge if Python might be a better solution. I recommend you take a look at [Tornado](http://tornadoweb.org) together with Jinja2 as template engine. NodeJS can sometimes get quite a *callback hell*, because of the way it does its asynchronicity, see e.g. http://callbackhell.com/

Note that in any case, for increased security and fast static file (CSS, JS) delivery, you might want to add a reverse proxy layer (Nginx usually provides better performance, but Apache works as well) before the NodeJS/Python server.